# Moose: subtype message does not show up

Tags: perl, moose, subtype

I am starting to use Moose. Here is my test package code:

```
package MyTest;
use Moose;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;

subtype 'MyStatus',
      as 'Int',
      where { $_ >= 0 && $_ < 10 },
      message { "Wrong status: $_" };

has status => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Maybe[MyStatus]' );

no Moose; 1;
```

And here is the program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MyTest;

my $t1 = MyTest->new('status' => 3);
$t1->status(100);
```

I expected to get a "Wrong status: 100" error, but instead I got this:

*Attribute (status) does not pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for 'Maybe[MyStatus]' with value 100 at accessor MyTest::s tatus (defined at MyTest.pm line 10) line 4*

How to make that message work?
Thank you!

Comment: Please don't retype error messages. Copy and paste them instead. There is a spelling mistake in your italic quote. ;-)

Comment: I copied and pasted it

Comment: Then it was probably a line break in the output because your terminal window was too small for the text. Never mind. ;)

Comment: Did you copy and paste it in two sections? There's a space in "MyTest::s tatus" :-)

Comment: That was a line brake in cmd window (on Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Maybe[]` eats the error message. If you remove it, it gives the `message` from your type.

```
has status => ( is => 'rw', isa => "MyStatus" );
```

Here's the error:

> Attribute (status) does not pass the type constraint because: Wrong status: 100 at accessor MyTest::status (defined at /home/foo/code/scratch.pl line 1331) line 4
>           MyTest::status('MyTest=HASH(0x3434c58)', 100) called at /home/foo/code/scratch.pl line 1337

It's because the `Maybe[]` itself is also just a function call. It checks the return value of calling the code ref behind `MyStatus` with the value you pass to the constructor (here that's `100`). If that type check passes , all is well. But if that check fails, `Maybe[]` issues its own error message.

You should ask yourself this question: Do you really want that the `status` can be `undef`? You didn't make it `required`, so you can omit it. Then your object doesn't have a status, which is different from having an *undefined* status. A status implies that the object is in a certain state, where the state has a meaning. If that state is undefined it sounds like trouble to me.

Comment: I cannot find the actual code that defines the `Maybe`. I must be searching for the wrong stuff.

Comment: Thank you! Any way to override this behavior? I need it to accept undef or small range of int values.

Comment: Well... _maybe_ there is. (Pun intended!) Check out https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Util::TypeConstraints#maybe_type-type

Comment: I might do some research later if I have time.